# Adding multiple points using Excel data in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, excel, multiple

How can I add more that one point to a specific location (defined by lat and long coordinates) using an Excel file?
My table looks like this:

| City name | Latitude | Latitude | A1 | A2 | A3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| New York | 40.785591 | -74.188452 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

So, what I need, is to add 3 different points on my map according to the data from columns A1, A2, A3. I know in ArcGIS you can define them in a query, but how can I do this in QGIS?

Comment: Are you open to open the csv (or if it is xlsx, export it to csv) with Python, create a shapefile and then add that to QGIS?

Comment: If yes, I can show you how to do that.

Comment: Thanks! I had some issues saving my excel files as .csv, but I managed to add my data from a .txt file. https://www.dropbox.com/s/kox5qpol54nqpuj/temp.txt?dl=0

Comment: 3 different points? Do you mean 3 points at the same location?

Comment: Exactly! I have a point that represents a city / village, and three or more points next to it, representing different data for that city.

Comment: You have two fields named `Latitude`

Comment: The one added here, yes. I pasted twice.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a text file (removed the spaces from the one you provided):

```
Name,Latitude,Longitude,A1,A2,A3
City1,44.499232,23.651273,1,1,1
City2,44.199232,23.251273,1,0,1
```

in `data.txt`, you can proceed with Python.

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point
```

Read in the file:

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.txt")
```

Load in the coordinates into shapely objects:

```
points = df.apply(lambda row: Point([row['Longitude'],row['Latitude']]),axis=1)
```

`points` now is:

```
0    POINT (23.651273 44.499232)
1    POINT (23.251273 44.199232)
dtype: object
```

Note that `df[['A1','A2','A3']].sum(axis=1)` returns:

```
0    3
1    2
dtype: int64
```

Indeed, we need to repeat point with index 0 3 times, the one with index 1 2 times. Let's do this, loading the result into a list called `geometry`:

```
geometry = []
for index, value in df[['A1','A2','A3']].sum(axis=1).items():
    for _ in range(value):
        geometry.append(points.loc[index])
```

Write to file:

```
gpd.GeoSeries(geometry).to_file("example.geojson")
```

`example.geojson` is now:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 23.651273, 44.499232 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 23.651273, 44.499232 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 23.651273, 44.499232 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 23.251273, 44.199232 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 23.251273, 44.199232 ] } }
]
}
```

Then you can load `example.geojson` to QGIS. The above code is available (and runnable) [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1-x_2zzRqDo-4Gg_WC96uvHLVD3EA-5MW?usp=sharing).

Comment: Thanks! But I'm totally new to this, and I know nothing about Python and how can I integrate it. Aren't any other solutions? I was hoping I can use something like in ArcGis, where you can define a query that says something like: A1=0 or A1>0 and you get the point on the map.

Comment: Just install this plugin, and you would be able to load your Excel files: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/SpreadsheetLayers/

Comment: I can get what I want by duplicating a layer and changing its marker colour and offset coordinates. This will do the trick. I can also use different .txt (which include the same lat and long coord.) files as layers and get the same result. 

@katagena I installed your recommended plugin, I get the new layer from an excel file, which is great, cause I don't have to work with csv or txt files, but how can I use the data from this layer (A1, A2) in order to show on my map 2 different points for the same location?

Comment: To show 2 points at the same location, it is not anymore a question of projection, but a question of symbology. You should open a new question! Try to search on gis.stack… there is a lot of similar questions!